# How to copy an Amazon RDS snapshot from a origin to another origin (region)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to copy an Amazon RDS snapshot from one region to another, but it does not work.

However, I am able to copy it in the same origin with the below code.

```
let URL = `https://rds.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=CopyDBSnapshot?SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier=${snapshot.DBSnapshotArn},?DestinationRegion=us-west-1?KmsKeyId=KmsKeyId?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=access-key/${date}/us-west-1/rds/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=${datetime}&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date&X-Amz-Signature=somevalue`;

let copyparams = {

    SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier: snapshot.DBSnapshotArn,
    TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier: snapshotname,
    CopyTags: true,
    SourceRegion: 'us-east-1',
    PreSignedUrl: url
};

rds.copyDBSnapshot(copyparams, function(err, result) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: not getting any error message, but it is not copying.

Comment: Are either of your `console.log()` statements being executed? Or can you put additional logging in there to see which if/else is being executed? Where are you running this code -- is it in AW Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

When copying a snapshot in the same region, you can use the dbSnapshot identifier, but when you copy it across region you must do three things different.

1: you must create the client in the destination region.

2: You must use the snapshot ARN instead of the snapshot identifier.

3: You must specify the source region.

Here is a nice walk through for python to automate the copying of RDS snapshots to a new region. Setup time is 5 minutes. It includes all the code needed as well as step by step instructions and a video walk through!

https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Automating_The_Cross_Region_Copy_Of_RDS_Snapshots